# Use jQuery to get session from Minecraft.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, minecraft

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [XmlHttpRequest error: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595515/xmlhttprequest-error-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)

I'm trying to use jQuery to get session id's and stuff from Minecraft.net using

```
https://login.minecraft.net?user=<username>&password=<password>&version=99999
```

But I can't get it because there is the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin". The data I receive from the server isn't even json which is even harder for me to figure out how to get data with javascript. I'm doing this so users won't go crazy with suspicions that I'm trying to steal their account.

This is something like what I'd receive

```
1343825972000:deprecated:SirCmpwn:7ae9007b9909de05ea58e94199a33b30c310c69c:dba0c48e1c584963b9e93a038a66bb98
```

Read more here. http://www.wiki.vg/Authentication#Login

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this in the browser, outside of a plugin installed by that user.

If you want to go to that url and get those values, you would need to use a server-side browser. Something like mechanize or phantomjs would be well suited for this sort of thing.